# Image overlay problem

Tags: android

I have a problem with two image overlay. One big(from camera) and one small sign which need to be stick over the big image in the corner. This overlay image have to be shown in the gallery. My sign image is located in drawable-hdpi.

```
bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bigImage);

bmSign = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(), R.drawable.sign);
bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(),
 bMap.getConfig());


    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaleStar, 0, 0, null);  
    i.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);

    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(computeWidth, imgHeight));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Problem is the size of the sign. Because all of the images are fixed height I need fixed sized sign to be apply on every image. With my code, on different resolution I have different sign image. It can happens sign to overlay 3/4 of the image.

How can I fix this?